# Word Field formatting using hex switch

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating an SDK and would like to use auto fields for the command numbering which is done in hex, and displayed in traditional hex formatting (0xNN). The problem I am running into is when the SEQ gets above 9, the formatting switch no longer works.

My current statement looks as follows.

```
{ SET m"{SEQ Command \s 1 \* Hex }" }{ m \# "'0x'00" }
```

The output I am getting is as follows:
0x07
0x08
0x09
**A   <-- Formatting breaks down**
**B**
**C**
**D**
**E**
**F**
0x10  <-- Formatting resumes

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using conditional formatting and moving the hex conversion until after the condition:

```
{QUOTE{IF{SEQ Command \s 1} < 16 "0x0" "0x"}{SEQ Command \c \*Hex  \*MERGEFORMAT}}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this accomplishes what I want.